# Java selection sort and insertion sort

Tags: java

```
//Justin Simpson
//CSC-251-FON01, Project 2
//Problem# 7, Page# 1003
//March 22, 2015


import java.util.Random;

/** 
 * This program uses sorting algorithms to take a array that is randomly generated arrays of 50 integers.
 * All four arrays are identical to the original array. Bubble sort, Insertions sort, selection  sort, and
 * Quick sort will be used to place the arrays in Ascending order.
 */


public class JustinSorting
{
   public static int count = 0;
   public static int count2 = 0;
   public static int size = 50;   //Holds the size of the arrays.

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       /**
        * Randomly creates the array then copies the same array to 4 other arrays. 
        */
       int[] original = new int[size];
       Random rand = new Random();
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       {
           original[i] = rand.nextInt(1000 - 100)+ 100;
       }
      int[] array1 = new int[size];
      int[] array2 = new int[size];
      int[] array3 = new int[size];
      int[] array4 = new int[size];

      System.arraycopy(original, 0, array1, 0, original.length);
      System.arraycopy(original, 0, array2, 0, original.length);
      System.arraycopy(original, 0, array3, 0, original.length);
      System.arraycopy(original, 0, array4, 0, original.length);

      //Calss each one of the sorting methods.
      bubbleSort(array1);
      insertionSort(array2);
      selectionSort(array3);
      quickSort(array4);

   }

  /**
   * Uses the bubble sort algorithm to sort the array.
   * @param array will pass the copied array.
   */
   public static void bubbleSort(int[] array)
   {  
      System.out.print("Bubble Sort:");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------");


      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\n|Original order:                        |");
      printArray(array);

      int lastPos;     // Position of last element to compare
      int index;       // Index of an element to compare
      int temp;        // Used to swap to elements

         // The outer loop positions lastPos at the last element
         // to compare during each pass through the array. Initially
         // lastPos is the index of the last element in the array.
         // During each iteration, it is decreased by one.
         for (lastPos = array.length - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--)
         {
            // The inner loop steps through the array, comparing
            // each element with its neighbor. All of the elements
            // from index 0 thrugh lastPos are involved in the
            // comparison. If two elements are out of order, they
            // are swapped.
            for (index = 0; index <= lastPos - 1; index++)
            {
               // Compare an element with its neighbor.
               if (array[index] > array[index + 1])
               {
                   count++;
                  // Swap the two elements.
                  temp = array[index];
                  array[index] = array[index + 1];
                  array[index + 1] = temp;
               }
               count2++;
            }

         }
      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");
      System.out.println("|Sorted order:                          |");
      printArray(array);
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");         
      System.out.print("|Swaps:" + count + "                              |");
      System.out.print("\n|Comparisons:" + count2 + "                       |");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------\n");

      count = 0;
      count2 = 0;

   }


   /**
    * Uses the insertion sort algorithm to sort the array.
    * @param array will pass the copied array.
    */
   public static void insertionSort(int[] array)
   {
      int unsortedValue;  // The first unsorted value
      int scan, scan1;    // Used to scan the array

      System.out.print("Insertion Sort: ");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------");

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\n|Original order:                        |");
      printArray(array);

      // The outer loop steps the index variable through 
      // each subscript in the array, starting at 1. The portion of
      // the array containing element 0  by itself is already sorted.
      for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++)
      {
         // The first element outside the sorted portion is
         // array[index]. Store the value of this element
         // in unsortedValue.
         unsortedValue = array[index];

         // Start scan at the subscript of the first element
         // outside the sorted part.
         scan = index;
         scan1 = index;

         // Move the first element in the still unsorted part
         // into its proper position within the sorted part.
         while (scan > 0 && array[scan-1] > unsortedValue)
         {
            array[scan] = array[scan - 1];
            scan--;
            count++;
            count2++;
         }
         count2++;

         // Insert the unsorted value in its proper position
         // within the sorted subset.
         array[scan] = unsortedValue;
      }
      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");
      System.out.println("|Sorted order:                          |");
      printArray(array);
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");         
      System.out.print("|Swaps:" + count + "                              |");
      System.out.print("\n|Comparisons:" + count2 + "                        |");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------\n");

      count = 0;
      count2 = 0;


   }

   /**
    * Uses the selection sort algorithm to sort the array.
    * @param array will pass the copied array.
    */
   public static void selectionSort(int[] array)
   {
      int startScan;   // Starting position of the scan
      int index;       // To hold a subscript value
      int minIndex;    // Element with smallest value in the scan
      int minValue;    // The smallest value found in the scan

      System.out.print("Selection Sort: ");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------");

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\n|Original order:                        |");
      printArray(array);


      // The outer loop iterates once for each element in the
      // array. The startScan variable marks the position where
      // the scan should begin.
      for (startScan = 0; startScan < (array.length-1); startScan++)
      {
         count++;
         // Assume the first element in the scannable area
         // is the smallest value.
         minIndex = startScan;
         minValue = array[startScan];

         // Scan the array, starting at the 2nd element in
         // the scannable area. We are looking for the smallest
         // value in the scannable area. 
         for(index = startScan + 1; index < array.length; index++)
         {
            if (array[index] < minValue || array[index] < minValue)
            {
               count2++;
            }
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
               minValue = array[index];
               minIndex = index;
               count2++;
            }
         }

         // Swap the element with the smallest value 
         // with the first element in the scannable area.
         array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
         array[startScan] = minValue;
      }
      // Display the array's contents.
      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");
      System.out.println("|Sorted order:                          |");
      printArray(array);
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");         
      System.out.print("|Swaps:" + count + "                               |");
      System.out.print("\n|Comparisons:" + count2 + "                        |");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------\n");


      count = 0;
      count2 = 0;
   }

   /**
    * Uses the quick sort algorithm to sort the array.
    * @param array will pass the copied array.
    */
   public static void quickSort(int array[])
   {

      System.out.print("Quick Sort: ");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------");


      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.println("\n|Original order:                        |");

      printArray(array);

      doQuickSort(array, 0, array.length - 1);

      // Display the array's contents.
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");
      System.out.println("|Sorted order:                          |");
      printArray(array);
      System.out.print("|                                       |\n");         
      System.out.print("|Swaps:" + count + "                              |");
      System.out.print("\n|Comparisons:" + count2 + "                        |");
      System.out.print("\n-----------------------------------------\n");

   }

   /**
      The doQuickSort method uses the QuickSort algorithm
      to sort an int array.
      @param array The array to sort.
      @param start The starting subscript of the list to sort
      @param end The ending subscript of the list to sort
   */

   public static void doQuickSort(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotPoint;

      if (start < end)
      {
         // Get the pivot point.
         pivotPoint = partition(array, start, end);

         // Sort the first sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, start, pivotPoint - 1);

         // Sort the second sub list.
         doQuickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, end);
      }
   }

   /**
      The partiton method selects a pivot value in an array
      and arranges the array into two sub lists. All the
      values less than the pivot will be stored in the left
      sub list and all the values greater than or equal to
      the pivot will be stored in the right sub list.
      @param array The array to partition.
      @param start The starting subscript of the area to partition.
      @param end The ending subscript of the area to partition.
      @return The subscript of the pivot value.
   */

   public static int partition(int array[], int start, int end)
   {
      int pivotValue;    // To hold the pivot value
      int endOfLeftList; // Last element in the left sub list.
      int mid;           // To hold the mid-point subscript

      // Find the subscript of the middle element.
      // This will be our pivot value.
      mid = (start + end) / 2;

      // Swap the middle element with the first element.
      // This moves the pivot value to the start of 
      // the list.
      swap(array, start, mid);

      // Save the pivot value for comparisons.
      pivotValue = array[start];

      // For now, the end of the left sub list is
      // the first element.
      endOfLeftList = start;

      // Scan the entire list and move any values that
      // are less than the pivot value to the left
      // sub list.
      for (int scan = start + 1; scan <= end; scan++)
      {
         if (array[scan] < pivotValue)
         {
            count++;
            endOfLeftList++;
            swap(array, endOfLeftList, scan);
         }
         count2++;
      }

      // Move the pivot value to end of the
      // left sub list.
      swap(array, start, endOfLeftList);

      // Return the subscript of the pivot value.
      return endOfLeftList;
   }

   /**
      The swap method swaps the contents of two elements
      in an int array.
      @param The array containing the two elements.
      @param a The subscript of the first element.
      @param b The subscript of the second element.
   */

   public static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b)
   {
      int temp;

      temp = array[a];
      array[a] = array[b];
      array[b] = temp;
   }

   public static void printArray(int[] array)
   {
      int index = 0;
      int index2 = 1;
      for (int element : array)
      {
         index++;
         if (index == 1 || index == 11 || index == 21 || index == 31 || index == 41 || index2 == 51)
            System.out.print("|");
         if (index % 10 != 0)
            System.out.print(element + " ");            
         else
            System.out.println(element + "|" );
      }
   }

}
```

My output from 50 integer randomly generated array copied 4 times into each sort algorithm is:

```
Bubble Sort:
-----------------------------------------
|Original order:                        |
|572 125 205 590 213 611 983 631 111 711|
|195 305 185 432 914 555 655 432 475 156|
|873 447 276 856 767 126 626 149 383 711|
|766 917 628 342 527 976 751 429 280 392|
|526 568 199 877 796 515 292 454 444 617|
|                                       |
|Sorted order:                          |
|111 125 126 149 156 185 195 199 205 213|
|276 280 292 305 342 383 392 429 432 432|
|444 447 454 475 515 526 527 555 568 572|
|590 611 617 626 628 631 655 711 711 751|
|766 767 796 856 873 877 914 917 976 983|
|                                       |
|Swaps:557                              |
|Comparisons:1225                       |
-----------------------------------------
Insertion Sort: 
-----------------------------------------
|Original order:                        |
|572 125 205 590 213 611 983 631 111 711|
|195 305 185 432 914 555 655 432 475 156|
|873 447 276 856 767 126 626 149 383 711|
|766 917 628 342 527 976 751 429 280 392|
|526 568 199 877 796 515 292 454 444 617|
|                                       |
|Sorted order:                          |
|111 125 126 149 156 185 195 199 205 213|
|276 280 292 305 342 383 392 429 432 432|
|444 447 454 475 515 526 527 555 568 572|
|590 611 617 626 628 631 655 711 711 751|
|766 767 796 856 873 877 914 917 976 983|
|                                       |
|Swaps:557                              |
|Comparisons:606                        |
-----------------------------------------
Selection Sort: 
-----------------------------------------
|Original order:                        |
|572 125 205 590 213 611 983 631 111 711|
|195 305 185 432 914 555 655 432 475 156|
|873 447 276 856 767 126 626 149 383 711|
|766 917 628 342 527 976 751 429 280 392|
|526 568 199 877 796 515 292 454 444 617|
|                                       |
|Sorted order:                          |
|111 125 126 149 156 185 195 199 205 213|
|276 280 292 305 342 383 392 429 432 432|
|444 447 454 475 515 526 527 555 568 572|
|590 611 617 626 628 631 655 711 711 751|
|766 767 796 856 873 877 914 917 976 983|
|                                       |
|Swaps:49                               |
|Comparisons:240                        |
-----------------------------------------
Quick Sort: 
-----------------------------------------
|Original order:                        |
|572 125 205 590 213 611 983 631 111 711|
|195 305 185 432 914 555 655 432 475 156|
|873 447 276 856 767 126 626 149 383 711|
|766 917 628 342 527 976 751 429 280 392|
|526 568 199 877 796 515 292 454 444 617|
|                                       |
|Sorted order:                          |
|111 125 126 149 156 185 195 199 205 213|
|276 280 292 305 342 383 392 429 432 432|
|444 447 454 475 515 526 527 555 568 572|
|590 611 617 626 628 631 655 711 711 751|
|766 767 796 856 873 877 914 917 976 983|
|                                       |
|Swaps:155                              |
|Comparisons:252                        |
-----------------------------------------
```

On insertion sort and selection sort my friend was saying the swaps and comparisons should be about the same. I am not sure if I am counting the swaps and comparisons differently than how I should be doing them. Also these are the algorithms that I have to use; even though they are the worse case scenario algorithms.

Comment: In your selection sort, you have `if (array[index] < minValue || array[index] < minValue)` followed by `if (array[index] < minValue)`. Did you reproduce your code correctly? As written, you are redundantly performing the same comparison three times. That's panic sort, not selection sort.

Comment: In your insertion sort you are incrementing your count2, counter variable twice. Perhaps this should only be incremented within the while loop of that method?
while (scan > 0 && array[scan-1] > unsortedValue)
         {
            array[scan] = array[scan - 1];
            scan--;
            count++;
            count2++;
         }
         count2++; // <-- check

Comment: @Saposhiente No that was something that I was messing with earlier thanks for the catch  on the code, sometimes I forget stupid things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back I created a testing program to visualize sorting. It came with a custom array type that registered the swap count and the comparison count - each on every access.

That being said, running a few tests with `n=1,000`:

```
Bubble Sort:

n      | Comparisons | Swaps
-------+-------------+---------
1000   | 499455      | 252385
1000   | 496944      | 253857
1000   | 499122      | 251105


Insertion sort:

n      | Comparisons | Swaps
-------+-------------+---------
1000   | 249434      | 248438
1000   | 256309      | 255315
1000   | 246906      | 245910
```

Generally, bubble sort has far more comparisons. This is due to the fact that elements have to be compared an average of `n/2` times, repeated for `n` times.

This is because the first element has to compare against the next `n-1` elements, the second element has to compare against the next `n-2`, and so on. You can see this since `(1000 / 2) * 1000 = 500,000`, which is within a few hundred of most runs.

---

Insertion sort however only has to go until it reaches an element less than the temporary one. Therefore it will compare an average of `n/2` times until it finds a lower element. It also has to perform an average of `n/2` comparisons - since the working array gradually gets bigger. Hence `(1000 / 2) * (1000 / 2) = 250000`, which is once again within a few thousand of most runs.

The first element would have to compare against one value. The second element would have to compare against either one value or two values. The third would be either one, two or three values, etc.

You're calculations are spot on and provable by examining the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Swaps and comparisons should not be about the same as each other.  You only swap after a comparison tells you to.  However, if your friend meant there isn't a huge difference between these sorting algorithms then it's more subjective.  It's not surprising that bubble sort is the slowest.

Consider renaming `count` and `count2`.  Those are horrible names. `countSwaps` and `countComparisons` are much better.

`while (scan > 0 && array[scan-1] > unsortedValue)`

is followed by

`count2++`

This is an undercount since two comparisons were just performed.

If I was doing this I'd take the lazy way out and write two helper functions that counted every time they were called.

```
public static int comparisionCount = 0;
public static int swapCount = 0;

public static void swap(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int temp = array[j];
    array[j] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
    swapCount++;
}


public static boolean isGreater(int left, int right) {
    comparisionCount++;
    return left > right;
}
```

Only use those to do swaps and comparisons and the counting magically happens without you having to worry about it.

For example:

`while (scan > 0 && array[scan-1] > unsortedValue)`

would become:

`while (isGreater(scan, 0) && isGreater(array[scan-1], unsortedValue))

One little nit pick:

`if (index == 1 || index == 11 || index == 21 || index == 31 || index == 41 || index2 == 51)`

could have just been:

`if (index % 10 == 1)`

Comment: `This is an undercount since two comparisons were just performed.` The `scan > 0` comparison is ignored, since really only the comparisons between elements matters. The reason these are tracked is if the elements have a heavy comparison cost, in which an algorithm with the fewest comparisons will run the fastest.

Comment: You make a fair point but actually comparisons can be important even when they aren't any more costly than comparing ints.  For example when the array is huge.  This code isn't trying to calculate a big O upperbound.  It's providing raw counts based on a specific input.  If it's going to claim to count the comparisons it should count the comparisons.

Comment: By that logic big O notation should include lower-degree values, such as `O(n^2 + 5n + 2)`. If the comparison takes 10ms for the elements, the nanosecond it takes to compare the ints doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @Obicere At times the elements are ints.  Again this isn't big O notation.  It's about truth in advertizing.  If you want to count it your way then say you're counting element comparisons.

Comment: Then your calculation is wrong. He swaps `i` for `i+1` and stores temporary variables and shifts elements on the stack. Numerous other operations which you failed to account for. If you're going to pick at one that isn't counted, you have to pick on them all. Then you might as well throw the results out the window because they're useless.

Comment: Numerous other operations != comparisons.  Element comparisons != comparisons.  It is what it is.  I think we've hashed it out enough that Justin can make up his own mind what he should count and how he should label it.

Comment: @Obicere CandidOrange(wouldn't let me add you too) This was very informative and gave me a lot to think about. Mainly in terms of how the math and coding both work together, and what is important and what is not important, when looking at the terms of sorting.Thank you both, I love programming even though I have really just started, the fact you are both so passionate about it makes me strive harder to be better.